# Using SASS with Aurelia's Skeleton Navigation project

Tags: sass, gulp, jspm, aurelia

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var to5 = require('gulp-babel');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var paths = require('../paths');
var compilerOptions = require('../babel-options');
var assign = Object.assign || require('object.assign');

// transpiles changed es6 files to SystemJS format
// the plumber() call prevents 'pipe breaking' caused
// by errors from other gulp plugins
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber
gulp.task('build-system', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.source)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.js'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
    .pipe(to5(assign({}, compilerOptions, {modules:'system'})))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write({includeContent: false, sourceRoot: paths.sourceMapRelativePath }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});

gulp.task('build-sass', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.sass + '**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'expanded',
            includePaths: [
                paths.sass,
                paths.jspmDir + '/github/Dogfalo/materialize@0.96.0/sass',
            ],
            errLogToConsole: true }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(paths.sourceMapRelativePath))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssOutput))
});

// copies changed css files to the output directory
gulp.task('build-css', function () {
    return gulp.src(paths.css)
        .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.css'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});

// copies changed html files to the output directory
gulp.task('build-html', function () {
  return gulp.src(paths.html)
    .pipe(changed(paths.output, {extension: '.html'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.output));
});


// this task calls the clean task (located
// in ./clean.js), then runs the build-system
// and build-html tasks in parallel
// https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-run-sequence
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    'clean',
    ['build-system', 'build-html','build-css','build-sass'],
    callback
  );
});
gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

I have gulp-sass working but I am not sure how to reference the System.config({
  "map": {  short hand to paths.

I am trying to use the materialize css framework so I imported it using

```
jspm install github:Dogfalo/materialize@0.96.0
```

which worked fine, but my concern now is that in my build task I have to reference the specific path to the sass folder including the version numbers in the includePaths property

If I look at the config.js file, jspm saved a reference to materialize under the System.config.map section, it seems if I could just reference the short hand materialize name in the code below this would solve my problem

Here is my build-sass task that I added to build.js

```
gulp.task('build-sass', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.sass + '**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({
            style: 'expanded',
            includePaths: [
                paths.sass,
                paths.jspmDir + '/github/Dogfalo/materialize@0.96.0/sass',  //I would like to just reference to shorcut path included in the config.js to materialize
            ],
            errLogToConsole: true }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(paths.sourceMapRelativePath))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssOutput))
});
```

Or if you have any better way to include a github package such as materialize using jspm and reference it in code letting jspm manage the package and version and just referencing the shorthand that jspm created

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**SASS build task**

You'll need to install gulp-sass, like you mentioned. Then, you'll want to add the following task to your build file. Notice the task includes plumber and changed as well. This will signal watch to rebuild your sass when you edit it and not break serving on syntax errors.

```
// compiles sass to css with sourcemaps
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
  return gulp.src(paths.style)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(changed(paths.style, {extension: '.css'}))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./styles'));
});
```

**Build task**

You'll also need to add this new sass build task to your general build task, so that it is included in the build pipeline.

```
gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    'clean',
    ['build-system', 'build-html', 'build-css'],
    callback
  );
});
```

**Using a CSS framework in code**

As you mentioned, having jspm install materialize will let jspm take care of all the heavy lifting for you. Once installed, jspm will modify the config paths to point to the right place. Then, when you need to reference it in code, you can import it normally. To install, you will want to add materialize to your `package.json` dependencies.

```
"jspm": {
   "dependencies": {
      "materialize": "github:Dogfalo/materialize@0.96.0",
```

Then, jspm will set up a map for you so you can use the normal module syntax.

```
import 'materialize/js/collapsible';
```

Materialize is not using the module syntax so, at the moment, you will need to (a) import each piece that you want specifically, as above, and (b) manually import jQuery, since materialize doesn't declare dependencies.

For more information, please see my full write up including examples here:
http://www.foursails.co/blog/building-sass/

Comment: if you find this helpful, please don't forget to accept and upvote

Comment: Matthew, thanks yeah I already got all the sass stuff working, but thanks for the clarification, my question was regarding having to manually reference sass libraries, the solution above only applies to your sass files but not library sass files like bootstrap-sass-official or materialize-sass, as you can see I reference materialize path as an additional path to watch for changes, what I want to know is can this be referenced automatically because jspm already knows the path to materialize or do I have to manually add it like it is now

Comment: oh i see. let me get back to you on that. bother me in the gitter channel if i let it slide. @davismj

Comment: "bother me in the gitter channel..." ? you're awesome, man :)